# Azure devops changed list of work items during a time period

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there a way to find out the list of Azure Devops work items that were changed in a given period of time ?

Something like "The list of test case work items that were changed in the last 60 days". The change can include changes to any of the fields configured for the work item.

Use case: Today, we have the manual test cases and they are being automated. If the manual test case changes, we need to update the automated test as well.

So, I'm looking for a way to find out the list of work items that were changed in any way in a given time period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure DevOps, go over to your project and under Boards you have a Queries tab.

You can create a query there using the Work Item Type [Any] and Changed Date > @StartDate("-60d").

I've added an image if it is easier.

There is also API [available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) for this, and you can automate that however you prefer.

[image]